# MQTT : Not able to send and receive messages at the same time and in the same file

Tags: python, mqtt

I have written a code that can do both publishing and subscribing in the same python file. My aim is to be able to send endlessly color temperature to a lamp and receive back its state (ON/OFF or online/offline).

However, when I run the code, I can send messages to the lamp but I don't receive anything (note that publisher and subscriber worked well separately)

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import sys
import time

topic = "testtopic/3" 
topic_casa = "testtopic/1"

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connection to the broker. Result : "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe(topic_casa, qos=1)
    client.publish(topic, light.circadianLight())

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    Message = str(msg.payload)
    print("[MSG RECEBIDA] Topico: "+msg.topic+" / Mensagem: "+Message)

def on_publish(client,userdata,result): 
    client.publish(topic, light.circadianLight())
    time.sleep(10)

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    if rc != 0:
        print("Unexpected disconnection.")  

try:

    print("[STATUS] Inicializando MQTT...")
    #inicializa MQTT:
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.on_connect     = on_connect
    client.on_message     = on_message
    client.on_disconnect  = on_disconnect

    client.on_publish = on_publish #with this callback we won't be able to 
#receive messages

    client.connect(Broker, PortaBroker, KeepAliveBroker)

    client.loop_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("\nCtrl+C pressionado, encerrando aplicacao e saindo...")
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is two fold, first that you are calling `time.sleep(10)` in the `on_publish()` callback.

This is blocking the MQTT client network loop so it will not send/receive any messages for 10 seconds every time you publish a message.

You should not be doing any blocking or long running tasks in any of the MQTT client callbacks.

The other problem is that without the sleep the client will spend all it's time publishing messages (because everytime it finishes publishing a message it trigger the `on_publish()` callback which kicks off another  publish. It will never get round to handing the incoming messages.

If you want to publish messages at a regular interval then you need to start a separate thread to do it, not try to do it in the callbacks.

Comment: I tried the code without time.sleep(10) but nothing has changed, I can send messages without receiving any message.

Comment: Did you also remove the `client.publish()` from the `on_publish()` callback? The last line of the answer is also important here

Comment: I removed 'client.publish()' as well and replaced it with a 'print' function, and it worked well!! I could now receive a message but send a unique message to the broker. So I need now to figure out how to publish messages at a regular time interval. Thank you! @hardillb